# Cloud functions provider with unlimited execution time

Tags: node.js, cloud, infrastructure

Where in cloud I can run Node.js scripts without UI ? Simple question BUT:

- My scripts will be able to run UNLIMITED time.
- I will be able to run\stop my scripts any time.
- It will be "serverless". (Not serverless like microservices with http output but like paas maybe)

I don't need UI because in my scripts there is no Express.JS or anything. Just simple scripts with Socket.IO connections (if this matter).

Basically I need node.js child_process.fork api but in cloud.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run the sort of program you mention on any VM instance you want, on any cloud provider you want. Yours is not an extraordinary requirement.

The two major cloud vendors have free introductory accounts. Others have very inexpensive options. I happen to like Digital Ocean for experimenting with services like yours.

If your program is compute-intensive you'll need to pay for a VM instance without compute throttling. The cheapest ones are throttled.

You application is not suitable for serverless or lambda deployment.